# Return the object with the max instance variable value

Tags: list, oop, object, list-comprehension

I have the following class:

```
class Node(object):
def __init__(self, id):
    self.stat = 1
    self.children = set()
    self.id= = id
```

There is a list which contains instances of this class

```
list = [instance_0, instance_1, instance_2]
```

I want my code to return the object that has the highest value in its `self.stat` variable

How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest not using `list` as a variable name... Let's call it `mylist` instead.

So you have:

```
mylist = [ instance_0, instance_1, instance_2 ]
```

Then this should give you the `stat` variables in another list:

```
objstats = [ x.stat for x in mylist ]
```

Then you can apply `max()` to find the largest, and `index()` to find which position it's in:

```
maxindex = objstats.index(max(objstats))
```

And then use that index to find your original object:

```
largest = mylist[maxindex]
```

You could of course combine the last two lines:

```
largest = mylist[objstats.index(max(objstats))]
```

Technically, you could combine the whole thing into one line, but since you reference `objstats` twice, it's more efficient to store it than to compute it twice.

Comment: thanks for the remark. sure `list` is an internal keyword so using is would not be wise. Also much thanks for the rest of the answer, especially for commenting what each step does. It helps a lot for novice programmers like me :)

Comment: interestingly enough I get the same result when I run `max(mylist)`, however not sure how correct is that

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne I'd have to tinker a bit to make sure, but I suspect when you do `max(mylist)`, it's doing `max()` on the first element added to each `Node`, which conveniently is what you want in this case - if you wanted `max()` over a different member, you'd have to take a different approach (like above). Also not sure if that's intentional behavior (i.e. is `max()` required to do it that way?) or a lucky side-effect...

Comment: as you say it is a lucky side-effect. For example, if we run `max()` on a list that contains strings, it returns the string starting with the character that is the farthest in the alphabet.

To extend my question I would like to be able to handle the situation when 2 (or more instances) have equal value saved in their `s` variable and that value is the biggest. 

at that case I would like to return a list of objects containing the highest value in `s`. Is that doable?

Comment: Not sure it's the best way, but something like `m=max(objstats); list_of_largest = [z for z in mylist if z.stat == m]` would be one way to accomplish that.